# VueJS: Swapping Form values of two forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

So I am working on an app where two address forms are almost similar and there is a checkbox called `Same as Billing` on one form and `Same as Shipping` on another so if they fill either one of the two forms, the values of that form transfer to another.

This works fine, when `Same as Billing` or `Same as Shipping` checkbox is checked, the other form is filled with values from another and vice versa. However, when I type and remove focus from any of those bind fields, their **typed** values does not appear.

[Here is by what I mean](http://jsbin.com/wozicegedo/edit?html,js,output)

So when you check the checkboxes, you would notice values are swapped however when you type some value in either of those textboxes and move focus away, they are overwritten by bound values.

VueCode:

```
new Vue({
  el:'body',
  props: {
    sameAsBox1: false,
    sameAsBox2: false
  },
  data: {
    first: 'Box 1 Contents',
    second: 'Box 2 Contents'
  }
});
```

So can someone please point out what Iam doing wrong here or it could be my logic isn't right it all for this simple task (billing, shipping example), I am new to VueJS and loving it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your behaviors totally worked out, but I believe you don't want to dynamically update the v-model bindings. Just bind the form inputs to the viewmodel and use Vue's watchers to update values when viewmodel data change.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  props: {
    sameAsBox1: false,
    sameAsBox2: false
  },
  data: {
    first: 'Box 1 Contents',
    second: 'Box 2 Contents'
  },
  watch: {
    first: function() {
      if (this.sameAsBox1) this.second = this.first;
    },
    second: function() {
      if (this.sameAsBox2) this.first = this.second;
    },
    sameAsBox1: function(val) {
      if (val) this.second = this.first;
    },
    sameAsBox2: function(val) {
      if (val) this.first = this.second;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />{{$data | json}}
<hr>

<div class="pull-left box">
  Box 1
  <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="first">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="sameAsBox2">Same As Box 2
</div>

<div class="pull-right box">
  Box 2
  <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="second">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="sameAsBox1">Same As Box 1
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this works for now but may be not optimal because i will have to write quite some conditions for each field in the form. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem you present. I too have trouble determining why your solution doesn't work. My guess is that vueJS is not happy with having a conditional statement in the v-model. For example, if you give the v-model an array that contains the conditional statement (like below), some weird data shows up in the $data.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="[sameAsBox2 ? second: first]">
```

However, I did find a workaround to the issue. namely by avoiding the conditional statement in the v-model part. I moved it over to the input tag itself like this:

```
<input class="form-control" v-if="sameAsBox2" type="text" v-model="second">
<input class="form-control" v-else type="text" v-model="first">
```

[See the jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/rebixiduye/edit?html,js,output)